# Как получить свойство background через jquery

Tags: jquery

В браузере google chrome все работает, а firefox ничего не находит, в консоле либо пусто либо null.

```js
$("html,body").on("click", ".k_s_main", function(){
  // получение фона
  var section_bg = $(this).parents(".k_section").css("background");
  //var myRe = /url\(\"(.+?)\"\)/ig;
  //var s_bg = myRe.exec(section_bg);
  console.log(section_bg);
})
```

```css
.k_section {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ed370216aefa86d4246055ccdc9394e5?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG');
}
.k_s_main {width: 32px;height: 32px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="k_section">
  <div class="k_s_main"></div>
</div>
```

Если конкретней, то нужно получить именно путь к фоновой картинке, а не весь url("... и т.д. но в итоге только в хроме все нормально работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо использовать background-image, после чего удаляем url и остается путь до картинки:

```
$("div").click(function() {
    var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
    bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");
    alert(bg);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло решение, но все же главный вопрос, почему не работает именно: $(id).css("background"); ведь в хроме работает.

Comment: @Владимир, потому что `background` это и `image` и `color`, т.е. оно выдаст два значение

Comment: L. Vadim, а если у него указано одинарные кавычки или вообще без них?

Answer (score 1):

1) Изображение нужно указывать через `background-image`
2) Получить одну ссылку можно регулярным выражением

```js
$(document).on("click", ".k_s_main", function(){
  // получение фона
  var section_bg = $(this).parents(".k_section").css("background-image").replace(/url\((?:\"|\')?(.+)(?:\"|\')?\)/, '$1');
  //var myRe = /url\(\"(.+?)\"\)/ig;
  //var s_bg = myRe.exec(section_bg);
  console.log(section_bg);
})
```

```css
.k_section {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ed370216aefa86d4246055ccdc9394e5?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG');
}
.k_s_main {width: 32px;height: 32px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="k_section">
  <div class="k_s_main"></div>
</div>
```

Проверил в firefox - всё работает